# Binding multiple csvs in R to output to a graph in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is an example of my data:

```
                      HUC8 YEAR RO_MM
       bcc1_45Fall_1020004 1961 112.0
       bcc1_45Fall_1020004 1962 243.7
       bcc1_45Fall_1020004 1963 233.3
       bcc1_45Fall_1020004 1964 190.3
     bcc1_M_45Fall_1020004 1961 100.9
     bcc1_M_45Fall_1020004 1962 132.3
     bcc1_M_45Fall_1020004 1963 255.1
     bcc1_M_45Fall_1020004 1964 281.9
     bnuesm_45Fall_1020004 1961  89.0
     bnuesm_45Fall_1020004 1962  89.5
     bnuesm_45Fall_1020004 1963 126.8
     bnuesm_45Fall_1020004 1964 194.3
    canesm2_45Fall_1020004 1961 186.6
    canesm2_45Fall_1020004 1962 197.4
    canesm2_45Fall_1020004 1963 229.1
    canesm2_45Fall_1020004 1964 141.8
```

Each of the similar prefixes represents (a segment of) a single `csv`. I have called them into a list and used `rbind` to link them. My goal is to have each `csv` represent a line of data, which  would look like this:

```
Name               
                        1961   1962   1963   1964   ...
   bcc1_45Fall_1020004  112.0  243.7  233.3  190.3
 bcc1_M_45Fall_1020004  100.9  132.3  255.1  281.9
 bnuesm_45Fall_1020004   89.0   89.5  126.8  194.3
canesm2_45Fall_1020004  186.6  197.4  229.1  141.8
```

I would then like to plot these lines in a line graph using `ggplot2`where each `Name` becomes a line of "RO_MM" data over 140 years. Remember, this is only a tiny sample. There are actually hundreds of files. I know that hundreds is too many for a graph and plan to do them in smaller groups, but I DO **NOT** need to grid them together. I have so far used this code which has provided the initial datalist above:

```
library(rio)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

file_names <- list.files("~/Desktop/Rproj/splitByHUCs45/a01020004/splFall")
data_list <- lapply(file_names, read.csv , header=TRUE, sep=",")
finalTable <- do.call(rbind, data_list)
```

I have found this code (below). It is not what I need because I don't need the mean of anything, but I saw that it used more than one `csv` for input, so I'm trying to make sense of it, but don't know how to make it work for me.

```
   #some pseudo data for testing
   my_other_data <- myData 
my_other_data$Data <- my_other_data$Data * 0.5 

pplot <- ggplot(data=myData, aes(x=Group, y=Data)) + 
   stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "line", color='red') +
   stat_summary(data=my_other_data, aes(x=Group, y=Data), 
                fun = mean, geom = "line", color='green') +
   xlab("Group") +
   ylab("Data")
pplot
```

That said, the page on creating a `reprex` said that I should provide you with this:

```
head(finalTable, 3) %>%
+    deparse()
 [1] "structure(list(HUC8 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c(\"bcc1_45Fall_1020004\", "            
 [2] "\"bcc1_M_45Fall_1020004\", \"bnuesm_45Fall_1020004\", \"canesm2_45Fall_1020004\", "             
 [3] "\"ccsm4_45Fall_1020004\", \"cnrmcm5_45Fall_1020004\", \"csiromk360_45Fall_1020004\", "          
 [4] "\"gfdlesm2g_45Fall_1020004\", \"gfdlesm2m_45Fall_1020004\", \"hadgem2cc_45Fall_1020004\", "     
 [5] "\"hadgem2es_45Fall_1020004\", \"hist_Fall_1020004\", \"inmcm4_45Fall_1020004\", "               
 [6] "\"ipslcm5_alr_45Fall_1020004\", \"ipslcm5_blr_45Fall_1020004\", \"ipslcm5amr_45Fall_1020004\", "
 [7] "\"miroc5_45Fall_1020004\", \"mirocesm_45Fall_1020004\", \"mirocesmchem_45Fall_1020004\", "      
 [8] "\"mricgcm3_45Fall_1020004\", \"noresm1m_45Fall_1020004\"), class = \"factor\"), "               
 [9] "    YEAR = 1961:1963, RO_MM = c(112, 243.7, 233.3)), row.names = c(NA, "                        
[10] "3L), class = \"data.frame\")"
```

I would appreciate getting help structuring the data so that I can bring it into `ggplot2` and how to make a graph with `ggplot2`, and explanations would be especially helpful. Thanks.

Comment: You should not use `deparse` to share data but use `dput` instead. The way it is shared we can't copy the data from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to use your example data (please use `dput(head(finalTable))` instead of deparse), but here is one potential solution using the data at the beginning of your question:

```
# Load libraries and data
library(tidyverse)
dat1 <- read.table(text = "HUC8 YEAR RO_MM
       bcc1_45Fall_1020004 1961 112.0
       bcc1_45Fall_1020004 1962 243.7
       bcc1_45Fall_1020004 1963 233.3
       bcc1_45Fall_1020004 1964 190.3
     bcc1_M_45Fall_1020004 1961 100.9
     bcc1_M_45Fall_1020004 1962 132.3
     bcc1_M_45Fall_1020004 1963 255.1
     bcc1_M_45Fall_1020004 1964 281.9
     bnuesm_45Fall_1020004 1961  89.0
     bnuesm_45Fall_1020004 1962  89.5
     bnuesm_45Fall_1020004 1963 126.8
     bnuesm_45Fall_1020004 1964 194.3
    canesm2_45Fall_1020004 1961 186.6
    canesm2_45Fall_1020004 1962 197.4
    canesm2_45Fall_1020004 1963 229.1
    canesm2_45Fall_1020004 1964 141.8",
           header = TRUE)

# Create your table
dat1 %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = YEAR, values_from = RO_MM)
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#  HUC8                   `1961` `1962` `1963` `1964`
#  <chr>                   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 bcc1_45Fall_1020004      112   244.    233.   190.
#2 bcc1_M_45Fall_1020004    101.  132.    255.   282.
#3 bnuesm_45Fall_1020004     89    89.5   127.   194.
#4 canesm2_45Fall_1020004   187.  197.    229.   142.

# Create a line plot (don't need to use the table for this)
dat1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = YEAR, y = RO_MM, group = HUC8, color = HUC8)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image: example_1.png]

And you can 'group' your results however you like, e.g.

```
dat1 %>%
  mutate(group = ifelse(str_detect(string = HUC8, pattern = "bcc"),
                        "group_bcc", "group_others")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = YEAR, y = RO_MM, group = HUC8, color = HUC8)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(group))
```

[image: example_2.png]

And, if you don't want a grid (like you said in your question):

```
dat1 %>%
  mutate(group = ifelse(str_detect(string = HUC8, pattern = "bcc"),
                        "group_bcc", "group_others")) %>%
  filter(group == "group_bcc") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = YEAR, y = RO_MM, group = HUC8, color = HUC8)) +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle("bcc csv files only")
```

[image: example_3.png]

You can "highlight" one specific line using a package (e.g. [gghighlight](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gghighlight/vignettes/gghighlight.html)) or just tell ggplot which colours you want to use, e.g.

```
dat1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = YEAR, y = RO_MM, group = HUC8, color = HUC8)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", viridis::viridis(3, alpha = 0.33)))
```

[image: example_4.png]

Comment: Well, that looks interesting but the actual output is 1155 lines, each of which prints to the console with a row number. So, best I can figure, in order to put ALL of the actual text in quotes, is that I'd have to copy it, paste it into Excel, remove the first column, and copy it back. It seems a little clunky. I have 30 of these to do. The rest of what you shared might work if I could get there. Thanks.

Comment: So you are having trouble importing the csv's into R? I assumed you had that part solved based on this sentence: "Each of the similar prefixes represents (a segment of) a single csv. I have called them into a list and used rbind to link them". If your csv's share the same layout (same column names), use the [vroom package](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/05/vroom-1-0-0/#reading-multiple-files) to load them and see if that solves your issue

Comment: So, I'm going to try it in segments, using `slice()`. I did do it the long way and it did work, but now I have to make it practicable. In a plot like this with many colors, I know I can set the overall palate but is it possible to make one single line black also?

Comment: No, it wasn't the importing the csvs, that's fine. It's that in my example I used 4 csvs. There are actually 21, each with 140 years laid out in columns in the console. It results in multiple screens worth of lines.

Comment: Right now you have given me `ggplot(aes(x = YEAR, y = RO_MM, group = HUC8, color = HUC8)) + geom_line()` That is great, but I need to single out one of the `csvs` to be black as a reference. I think I should just add it as a separate `csv` so that I can dictate the color. Is that something you know how to do? When I have this worked out, your solution gets a "Solved".

Comment: Ok, this worked in a broad sense and I'm giving you credit, but it's clunky. I'm going to ask again in a different way.